# forfiles how to move a directory to another directory

Tags: windows, copy, robocopy

I'm trying to move a directory which certain date parameter to another directory..
This is the command I'm using:
FORFILES -p C:\test1\ /S /D -3 /C "cmd /c if @isdir == TRUE move C:\test2\"

I want to move subdirectories inside test1 to the test2 directory if they meet those parameters.
Right now, the script will move test2 to test1.... why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only give the `move` command one parameter, it moves the given file/directory to the current directory.  You need

```
FORFILES -p C:\test1\ /S /D -3 /C "cmd /c if @isdir == TRUE move @path C:\test2\"
```

so that `move` knows what file/directory (in `@path`) it should be trying to move.

Comment: Hi, Ok it worked, but 1 problem, if I have subdirectories under 'test1', it will only move files from 1 subdirectory, the other subdirectories he get 'cannot find the file'
        1 dir(s) moved.
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified